# How to pass parameters to Python from Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins

I got following file and would like to use parameters instead. How can I pass them through in Python?

```
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from urllib.parse import quote
from io import StringIO
import smtplib, ssl
import mimetypes
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email import encoders
import logging


username = "xxxxx"
password = "yyyyyy"
port = 3306
database = "esxinfo"

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://test:%s@jenkins:3306/esxinfo' % quote('xxxxxx'))
sql = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM esx_info', engine)

df = pd.DataFrame(sql)
textStream = StringIO()
df.to_csv(textStream,index=False)

def sendmail():
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    my_address ="mygmail@gmail.com"
    app_generated_password = "xxxxxxxxxxxx" 
    msg['Subject'] = "The Email Subject"
    msg["From"]= my_address
    msg['To'] = "yyyyyyyyyyy
    msg.add_header('Content-Type','text/html')
    #msg.set_content("This is the body of the email") 
    #msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'html'))
    textStream = StringIO()
    df.to_csv(textStream,index=False)
    msg.attach(MIMEApplication(textStream.getvalue(), Name="test.csv"))
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465) as smtp:
            smtp.login(my_address,app_generated_password)    #login gmail account
            print("sending mail")
            smtp.send_message(msg)   #send message 
            print("mail has sent")

sendmail()
```

Say I want to pass

```
my_address ="mygmail@gmail.com"
```

how do I do that without putting in code? I want to run this with parameters from Jenkins.

Comment: If you are running this from jenkins, you should look into command line arguments https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins has a [plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/python/) for Python scripts, you can add parameters to your "Parameter build" for instance adding a string parameter and then call them like `%MY_ADDRESS%` in the script itself.

However, the downside of a parameter build is being asked to fill in this information every job you kick off.... You could of course potentially automate the information if its the same every run.

For example, I have a script which needs to delete a workspace every night to clean. The parameter is "Branch" and it passes in my branch name, in the script itself I call the path by `C:\Path\To\%Branch%\`